# Is there any codeigniter authentication library that also supports login with FB/Google/Twitter?

Tags: facebook, codeigniter, authentication

I'm writing my first codeigniter application and I want to have FB/Google/Twitter authentication along with normal authentication system, all well integrated.

Is there any codeigniter authentication  library that supports FB/Google/Twitter login(or at least just FB Login)?

Comment: at first you must say what is your programming language

Comment: All CodeIgniter application code is in PHP

Answer (score 0):

For Facebook support, try https://github.com/elliothaughin/codeigniter-facebook

The same github profile used to have an integrated library for all the services you mentioned, but that seems to have been removed.